# update dataGrid back to ef from anonymous type

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

The following code shows into dataGrid result from two tables

But I understand that I can not update the data back into the DB (since it shows anonymous type)

```
public class NameAndDone
{
    public string document_Name { get; set; }
    public bool ? document_Done { get; set; }
}


       vagEntities projectE = new vagEntities();
       var doc = from c in projectE.Person_Documents
                  join cw in projectE.Documents on c.Document_Id equals cw.Document_Id
                  where c.Person_Id == selc   
                  select new NameAndDone { document_Name = cw.Document_Name,document_Done = c.Document_done};

       carsGrid.ItemsSource = doc;
```

and in the xaml

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" RowHeight="30" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="15,15,15,96" x:Name="carsGrid" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Path=document_Name}" MinWidth="100" Header="Documents"  />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Binding="{Binding Path=document_Done}" Header="Done" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My question is: Is it possible to update with the saveChanges () function?
Or I need to change all the code (hope not)

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps (even if I can not understand)

Please, does anyone have an idea?